# How can I add custom Prism.js styles in ReactTinyMCE for codesample formatting and highlighting?

Tags: reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-plugins, prismjs

Here is my TinyMCE configuration for react I
used **[@tinymce/tinymce-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-react)**.

I checked on how to add customized theme width Prism.js but
it's not working.
I wanted to use **okaidia** theme

[image]

Anyone who knows how to use custom stylings for **codesample**
with tinymce && prism.js other than default stylings can help.

The default format for codesample looks like this below but I want to use **okaidia** theme and add other custom prism styles.

[image]

```js
import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";

const TextEditor = () => {
  const onChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.getContent());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        id="my-file"
        type="file"
        name="my-file"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        onChange=""
      />
      <Editor
        initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
        init={{
          selector: "textarea",
          plugins: "codesample image",
          toolbar: "codesample",
          codesample_global_prismjs: true,
          codesample_languages: [{ text: "Javascript", value: "javascript" }],
        }}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextEditor;
```